# Is this possible in Latex? Creating a new environment for notices in technical documents

Tags: tables, environments

I don't even know how to title my request. I am also not including any code, because I have absolutely no starting point.

I'm writing a technical document and once in a while I need to put a notice/warning into the text.

What I want to do is best described by seeing what I've done in Word:

[image]

[image]

I'd be so grateful for any help!

Comment: I would use tcolorbox.

Comment: The short answer is : yes !

Comment: Yes, possible, but it does not look very nice, in my point of view